# Increase size of plus/minus buttons of "input number" using Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In my web app, I have an element `<input type="number">`:
[image]

The plus/minus buttons are okay-ish sized when working on a desktop PC. However, on a tablet or smartphone they're pretty small and I'd like to either increase the buttons or show them side by side.

Since I'm using Bootstrap, I was wondering whether there is a built-in way of doing so? Or do I have to change it to `<input>`, add two buttons for in-/decrementing the value and style them separately?

Thx!

Comment: first try to add class to your input <input class="form-control"\